# How to do full replication of data to new cassandra clustered node?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I have 2 node Cassandra cluster. I wish to replicate the complete data into a 3rd node so that the 3rd node will have complete data (for some special needs). All the 3 nodes will have Cassandra version 2.1.8.

With replication factor 3, I plan to follow as per doc in [Adding nodes to an existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html#task_ds_in2_qjq_gk)

Question:

1. Is it correct approach ? If so, when can I confidently say data
   replication is complete (assuming I restrict inflow of data)
2. Can I replicate only a subset of tables from a cassandra keyspace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that is the correct approach.  Although, I don't see a step to adjust the replication factor on your keyspace for your datacenter.  Make sure you do that just before adding your new node.  Also, as your RF = number of nodes, you won't need to run `nodetool cleanup` on the existing nodes.
2. No, you cannot.  You *can* replicate only a subset of *keyspaces* differently, but not actual tables themselves.  If you have tables that need to be replicated differently, you should put them in their own keyspaces.